# How to use sed to find the strings between 2 patterns?

Tags: sed, text-processing

I have file content like this:

```
aaa accounting exec ...
aaa accounting exec ...
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting network ..
aaa accounting connection ..
aaa accounting system ..
!
aaa accounting exec default
 action-type start-only
 group tacacs+
!
aaa accounting exec default stop-only group tacacs+
```

The output should be like this:

```
aaa accounting exec default ..
aaa accounting exec default
 action-type start-only
 group tacacs+
!
aaa accounting exec default ..
```

I have tried following `sed` command:

```
sed -n '/aaa accounting exec default/,/!/p' AboveFileContent.txt
```

But it's not produce what I want.

What would be the solution? I have tried using `awk` also but same result is coming. What would be the command to get the exact output?

Comment: First line of your output `aaa accounting exec default ..` points to what line(s) in your input file??

Comment: aaa accounting exec default 1. aaa accounting exec default 2 . Consider all lines are unique but in some line starting strings are matching.

Comment: it may be middle content of whole file or may be starting line in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use awk for this:

```
awk '
    /aaa accounting exec default/ {print; exec=1; next} 
    exec {
        if (/^ /) {print; next} else if (/^!/) {print}
        exec=0
    }
' filename
```

Passing the pattern, use awk's `-v` option, and then the pattern match operator `~`:

```
awk -v patt='aaa accounting exec default' '
    $0 ~ patt {print; exec=1; next} 
    exec {
        if (/^ /) {print; next} else if (/^!/) {print}
        exec=0
    }
' filename
```

Comment: See! Far simpler.

Comment: Thanks for giving this simple code. But in this code how to externalize the patterns. I mean how do I pass /aaa accounting exe default/ pattern from outside. I want to take these pattern as input from user.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get data structured in the form:

```
aaa ...
 ...
 ...
!
```

You need to make `sed` aware that the indented blocks matter. A crude way might be to write a loop in `sed`:

```
sed -n '
# Create a label named 'start'
:start
# If the line matches the beginning of a block, 
# jump (branch) to the label named section
/aaa accounting exec default/ b section
# If we didn't branch, get the next line
n
# Jump back to the start label
b start
# The label named section
:section
# print the line
p
n
# Keep looping to section for the lines we need
/^ /,/!/ b section
# If we don't have any more lines to loop on, 
# jump back to the beginning
b start
'
```

In one line:

```
$ sed -n ':start; /aaa accounting exec default/ b section; n; b start; :section; p; n; /^ /, /!/ b section; b start' test.txt
aaa accounting exec default start-stop group tacacs+
aaa accounting exec default
 action-type start-only
 group tacacs+
!
aaa accounting exec default stop-only group tacacs+
```

It could be done in a more readable way using `awk`, `perl` or `python`, I'd guess.

Comment: Thanks! Its working fine with start & end as simple string.But it's not working in case if I provide /aaa accounting .+/ as a pattern. Please help.

Comment: @user1939205 `+` is part of extended regular expressions (ERE). Try `sed -r`, or escape the `+`: `.\+`.