# How do I write perl code for following example?

Tags: command-line, programming, perl

**I have file content like this:**

```
aaa accounting exec ...
aaa accounting exec ...
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting commands ..
aaa accounting network ..
aaa accounting connection ..
aaa accounting system ..
!
aaa accounting exec default
 action-type start-only
 group something+
!
aaa accounting exec default stop-only group tacacs+
```

**The output should be like this:**

```
aaa accounting exec ..
aaa accounting exec ..
aaa accounting exec default
 action-type start-only
 group something+
!
 aaa accounting exec default stop-only group tacacs+
```

**I want to get output between following 2 patterns:**

```
Start Pattern: /aaa accounting exec .+/ 
End Pattern: /!/
```

What will be the easiest perl code to produce above output?

Comment: Does it have to be Perl? Maybe Awk is a more suitable tool for such tasks. It's also not clear to me how the desired output is achieved, because not all lines match the pattern you gave. Maybe give a simpler example?

Comment: Yeah maybe awk code will be simple for this type of problem. But still for some reason I have to use Perl. I have edited the problem to make it simple to understand.

Comment: This is the same question of [your old question](http://askubuntu.com/q/564668/283843). and still unclear what you are asking. if you want the lines between `aaa accounting exec .+` and `!`, the given output(which is your desired result) doesn't the what you asked.

Comment: Yeah but this time need perl code. ( if it is possible in perl )

Comment: Despite your edit, I'm still not clear how your desired output is to be derived from your input.

Comment: You can refer my similar question: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/564668/how-to-use-sed-to-find-the-strings-between-2-patterns)

Comment: What I understand from your pattens and input file you will have [multiple outputs](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9640473/) but I don't know how did you get the result like above in your question.

Comment: @KasiyA Just observer the output: The starting citation is: **aaa accounting exec .+** because of this I am getting lines 1, 2, 3 and 6 resp. in output and my end citation is **!**  (exclamation mark) because of this I am getting output from line 3 to 5.

Comment: So the conclusion is that at least starting citation should get match from the input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer will be:**

```
perl -ne ' if($p==1){if(/^ /){ print; next;} elsif(/^!/){print;}$p=0} 
if(/aaa accounting exec .+/){print;$p=1}' text.txt
```

Where **text.txt** is the file containing above text mentioned in the question.